# Export multiple Lotus Notes Documents to RTF

Tags: lotus-notes

in Notes after opening a document I am able to Export it as RTF via File -> Export -> As RTF.
If I mark multiple documents instead of opening one after another that option is missing.

Is there any way to call the internal Export function with a Notes Agent?

I know about [this Export script](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#rtfexport) but the built-in function is a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that it's a repetitive task and you don't want to use that script to export the documents, I would suggest an outside-the-box solution: you can use a software like [AutoHotkey](https://www.google.com.bo/search?q=autohotkey) to simulate the keystrokes and clicks.

You will have to write the macro but it should work. I use it myself to do similar tasks as replicate a Lotus Notes app (Key Alt + F, Key R, Key R, wait, Keys SERVER03, wait, Enter, wait, Enter)

Answer (score 0):

I found this quite easy [solution](http://www.iminstant.com/iminstant/iminstant.nsf/d6plinks/ctyr-7h6s6r).

Just invoke the field wanted over http and save it with the right codepage!
I had nothing to change in my databases, views or forms!

Michael

Comment: This exports a Notes rich text field as HTML, which is not the same as exporting a document as an RTF file. Useful, though.